# DragBox change color while drawing

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In order to help users to draw a boxarea with minimum of 100 px at width and height, I've thought to start drawing in red color (fill and border of box) and then change automatically to green when it reaches the 100 px mentioned while user is drawing the feature.

Any idea how to do this?

I got it something like that when user has finished drawing, but in my opinion, that behavior is not enough comfortable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/41j800kv/

Found a better solution. Put these conditions inside a `ol.interaction.Draw#StyleFunction`:

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: vectorSource,
  type: 'LineString',
  maxPoints: 2,
  style: function(feature){
    var style;
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var extent = geometry.getExtent();
    var topLeft = 
        map.getPixelFromCoordinate(ol.extent.getTopLeft(extent));
    var bottomLeft = 
        map.getPixelFromCoordinate(ol.extent.getBottomLeft(extent));
    var topRight = 
        map.getPixelFromCoordinate(ol.extent.getTopRight(extent));

    var width = topRight[0] - topLeft[0];
    var height = bottomLeft[1] - topLeft[1];
    coords_element.innerHTML = 
      'width: ' + width + '<br>height: ' + height;

    if (width > 100 && height > 100) {
      style = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'red',
          width: 2
        })
      });
    } else {
      style = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#ffcc33',
          width: 2
        })
      });
    }

    return [style];
  },
  geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
    if (!geometry) {
      geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon(null);
    }
    var start = coordinates[0];
    var end = coordinates[1];
    geometry.setCoordinates([
        [start, [start[0], end[1]], end, [end[0], start[1]], start]
    ]);
    return geometry;
  }
});
```

---

<strike>Take this piece of code and put some conditions on it:</strike>

Comment: I guess I missed something, but anyway it was a good exercise.

Comment: Dont worry, at least he has two solutions to choose from. Instead of nothing .....:)))))))

Comment: Really I use ol.interaction.Draw like your example's code. I've added pavlos suggestion to change style inside your geometryFunction:
    if (width>100 && height>100){
    $('.ol-control').removeClass('ol-control').addClass('ol-mydragbox');
    $('.ol-control').removeClass('ol-control').addClass('ol-mydragbox');
    }

But it doesn't work, not errors, but not color change... :-(

Comment: @ToniBCN which solution would you like to use?

Comment: I like your solution @JonatasWalker, but as you mentioned, is incomplete, and I didn't got with the missing part of code to make the color change.

Comment: I didn't say it's incomplete, it's just not a solution for `ol.interaction.DragBox`, it's a solution for `ol.interaction.Draw`. See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/41j800kv/).

Comment: Great !! It works in my app. Thans a lot @JonatasWalker

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of ol3. 3.13.1 you may do the following to achieve your goal.

1. Create a map with a layer and add a dragbox interaction

   ```
   var raster =  new ol.layer.Tile({
     source: new ol.source.OSM()
   });   

   var map = new ol.Map({
   layers: [raster],
   target: 'map',
   view: new ol.View({
   center: [0, 0],
   zoom: 2
    })
   });

   var selectOnBoxInt = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
     condition  : ol.events.condition.always
   });
   map.addInteraction(selectOnBoxInt);
   //set it active on start up
   selectOnBoxInt.setActive(true);
   ```
2. Create two css classes holding styles for your drawbox

   ```
   //this is the deafult 
   .ol-dragbox {
     background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
     border-color: rgba(2500,0,0,1);
     border-width:2;
    }
    //this is when width,height>100     
   .ol-mydragbox {
     background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.4);
     border-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
     border-width:2;
   }
   ```
3. asign a `boxdrag` event to your drawbox interaction so you can truck down its width, height and make the style changes. For this action, and for the sake of time, I use jquery. You may use your imagination to do it without jquery.

   ```
   selectOnBoxInt.on('boxdrag',function(e){
   var width = Math.abs(e.target.box_.endPixel_[0] - e.target.box_.startPixel_[0]);
   var height = Math.abs(e.target.box_.endPixel_[1] - e.target.box_.startPixel_[1]);
   if (width>100 && height>100){
   $('.ol-dragbox').removeClass('ol-dragbox').addClass('ol-mydragbox');
   $('.ol-box').removeClass('ol-box').addClass('ol-mydragbox');
   } else {
   $('.ol-mydragbox').removeClass('ol-mydragbox').addClass('ol-dragbox');
   }
   });
   ```

And a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/q5yns26k/) to see it in action.

Comment: This solution sounds good !!. I've to upgrade OL version of my webapp and try to adapt it because I have already made some changes. I will tell you what about. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Really I use ol.interaction.Draw instead ol.interaction.Dragbox but the boxdrag event as you posted in your example, doesn't work. Not errors, and not tracking info in console... :-(

Comment: If you use  ol.interaction.Draw you have to do it the other way around. My example is working fine check the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/q5yns26k/) to verify your self. Box is changing color because `boxdrag` event is fired.

Comment: True @pavlos your example works fine. But due to some changes, now, I need to use ol.interaction.Draw and then, it doesn't work. Thanks for your suport.

Comment: No prombs amigo. `boxdrag` wont work for draw interaction, thats true. You better stick with @jonatas solution. glad to help.